# Global CSS doesn't apply to a class section in Pelican's bootstrap3 theme

Tags: html, css, pelican

I've got a blog.  I use Pelican 4.8 and the theme pelican-bootstrap3.  It works, but I wanted to have dark mode that follows the OS general setting.  To do this I added some custom CSS:

./content/extra/custom.css

```
your @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background: #000;
    color: #7fff00;
    outline: 5px dashed #753;
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body {
    background: #fff;
  }
}text
```

This also works, mostly.  My site now follows the operating systems light/dark them...apart from the sidebar.  I'm not a web coder, so I'm fumbling my way through this.

The generated html that Pelican spits out according to the page source, looks like this:

https://paste.centos.org/view/191ae06e

The first several lines (the about me section) follows dark mode as expected, but then I get to the sidebar, and the background colour of the sidebar, starting at the social links, never changes.  It starts here:

```
<section class="well well-sm">
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
```

So I guess my question is, how do I add CSS or html to tell a section class to follow my OS system-wide theme?  I'm using pygments style monokai if that makes any difference.

tried system wide custom CSS, but it didn't take effect in the sidebar

Comment: _"and the background colour of the sidebar, starting at the social links, never changes"_ - presumably, because that sidebar has its _own_ background color applied ...? You did nothing but change the background of body so far, so in all places where an element has its _own_ background, that will of course not achieve much.

Comment: thanks, yes, I understand, but how would I change it?  I think a lot of that is html, not css, and i've found the colour setting in sidebar.html and changed it/regenerated the page and nothing happened.  It seems as if it's taking it's instructions from some style policy higher up in the chain. how can I identify what is dictating that colour?  Once I identify that I'll be able to change it manually and then that will give me the info I need to see if I can apply my CSS policy as a html equivalent in that specific section.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to inspect the element, the CSS panel will show you which styles actually apply based on which rules.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  The Inspector showed it as being a section class called .well.  I search for that in all files and found it in bootstrap.cosmo.min.css, and was able to just remove the background-color: #f5f5f5 setting from that section.  It's white now but it does follow dark mode with that removed.